# SQL query base on field of migration time

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-schema

### Table

The Data Structure such as the following:

- [Table] Members, including member profile
- [Table] Departments, including department for member
- [Table] Migrate, Record Member migration between department

### Schema

1. Members

   - id (int)
   - name (char)
2. Departments

   - id (int)
   - name (char)
3. Migrate

   - id (int)
   - member_id (int)
   - department_id (int)
   - update_time (datetime) - Default: CURRENT_DATETIME

### Data Examples

- Members

  1. 1, Tom
  2. 2, Gary
- Department

  1. 1, A
  2. 2, B
- Migrate

  1. 1, 1, 1, 2013-05-01 00:00:00 (New Member in Department A joined on 2013/05/01)
  2. 2, 2, 1, 2013-05-02 00:00:00 (New Member in Department A joined on 2013/05/02)
  3. 3, 1, 2, 2013-05-08 00:00:00 (Migrate to Department B)

### Question

When a member created, I insert a row to Migrate table with inserted time.

I can query by:

```
SELECT name 
FROM department WHERE id = (SELECT Top 1 department_id 
                            FROM Migrate
                            WHERE update_time <= GETDATE() 
                            ORDER BY update_time DESC)
```

getting user department name.

And if member migrate from department A to department B, I will insert a new row to record with department B id and migrating time (that now).

But the question is how could I get the department's member list at a specific time like '2013-05-01'

I need a SQL Server solution, thanks for your read.

Comment: Show tables with columns and sample data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
select Members.name , Departments.name  from Members 
inner join

(SELECT max(id) migrateid, member_id 
FROM Migrate
WHERE update_time <= '2013-05-08' 
group by member_id )a

on Members.id=a.member_id

inner join Migrate

on a.migrateid=Migrate.id

inner join Departments

on Departments.id=Migrate.department_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can already get member department at specific time through subquery.

I need a answer, input date and department(s) to get the specific time who are in.

Comment: Oh, I just add WHERE for Joined table to get specific department, Thank a lot :)